# opencv selective search not returning region proposals (silent fails)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, opencv3.0

I am using `opencv contrib` for selective search. And I am trying something very simple to see if I can get good rps. It just runs through, *without* exceptions, but generates no rectangles.

I have:

- reinstalled opencv contribs module

- checked if other opencv models are working, (they are!)
- run multiple images as well

I have been stuck on this for a while and no idea what to do.

```
frame_cv = cv2.imread(fn)
h,w,_ = frame_cv.shape

#~let;s get out frame width to ~640xsomething, it's more manageable
if w > 600:
    ratio = 600.0/float(w)
    frame_cv = cv2.resize(frame_cv,(0,0),fx=ratio,fy=ratio)
ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(frame_cv)
rects = ss.process()
print("[+] rects: ", len(rects))
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the type of selective search like switchToSelectiveSearchFast().
Here is the sample-

```
frame_cv = cv2.imread(fn)
h,w,_ = frame_cv.shape

#~let;s get out frame width to ~640xsomething, it's more manageable
if w > 600:
    ratio = 600.0/float(w)
    frame_cv = cv2.resize(frame_cv,(0,0),fx=ratio,fy=ratio)
ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(frame_cv)
ss.switchToSelectiveSearchFast()
rects = ss.process()
print("[+] rects: ", len(rects))
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your choice, you could do `fast` or `quality` search.

Fast method finish the job early with less proposed regions.

The quality method takes more time (~4 times) to finish the job but proposes more regions

After you set the base image

```
image = cv2.imread(fn)
ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(image)

if method == "fast":
    ss.switchToSelectiveSearchFast()
else:
    ss.switchToSelectiveSearchQuality()
```

To see the performance between the methods, you could set time:

```
start = time.time()
rects = ss.process()
end = time.time()
```

Finally, we can see the accuracy between the methods

```
for i in range(0, len(rects), 100):
    output = image.copy()

    for (x, y, w, h) in rects[i:i + 100]:
        color = [random.randint(0, 255) for j in range(0, 3)]
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

For instance:

[image]

The fast method took 1.3286 seconds and propose 2068 regions:

[image]

The quality method took 4.2615 seconds and propose 6356 regions.

[image]